# MySQL: Group By Clause

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I need some help with a group by mysql query clause.

**Medals Table** *(this holds all the medals)*:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| medal_id | medal_level | medal_name      | medal_type | medal_icon    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|        1 |           1 |    1 post medal |          1 | icon_file.png |
|        2 |           2 |  1 thread medal |          2 | icon_file.png |
|        3 |           1 |    2 post medal |          1 | icon_file.png |
|        4 |           2 | 2 threads medal |          2 | icon_file.png |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Users Medals Table** *(this holds the medals which users have won)*:

```
+--------------------------------+
|medal_id |user_id | earnedtime  |
|--------------------------------|
|       1 |      1 | 1313548360  |
|       2 |      1 | 1313548365  |
|       3 |      1 | 1313548382  |
|       4 |      1 | 1313548410  |
+--------------------------------+
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT m.*, u.*
FROM users_medals u
LEFT JOIN medals m ON (u.medal_id=m.medal_id)
WHERE u.user_id IN(1)
GROUP BY m.medal_type
ORDER BY u.earnedtime
```

What this is intended to do is display medals users have earned (this is a plugin for a bulletin board system). It selects and displays the medals where the users medal id is equal to the medal id in the table that holds all the medals.

This works fine, however, it's not displaying the latest medal. It's only displaying the following medal id's: 1, 2. It should be displaying 3 and 4.

***Additional Info:*** I only want to display one medal from each medal type. So for example, if the user has earned two "post medals", only the latest one earned will be displayed, along with any other medals earned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Dalen I need to somehow group the medal_type's, so it only displays one medal for each type.

Comment: If it is displaying medal_id 1 (type 1) and medal_id 2 (type 2).  Then it is only displaying 1 medal per type.  So it's working?

Comment: @webbiedave Yes, however it's not showing the "latest" one earned.

Comment: @Spencer: Sorry, I deleted my comment because Matt H. heavily edited his which made mine moot. I understand your requirement now. You need the latest medals earned, one of each type.

Comment: Selecting columns that are not mentioned in the 'GROUP BY' clause can lead to unpredictable results -- "The rule is that one should
not have columns in your select that are not in the group
by section, except for the grouping functions.
MySQL though does allow it, but results can be strange as
above" [link] (http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/158524)

Comment: you'd have to try `order by earned DESC`  to make the newest medal show up first in the results. MySQL tends to pick grouped values by the first one it encounters, so the ordering will make it pick the latest medal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.*, u.*
  FROM users_medals u
  LEFT JOIN medals m ON u.medal_id = m.medal_id
  WHERE u.user_id IN (1)
  AND u.earnedtime = (
    SELECT MAX(users_medals.earnedtime) FROM users_medals
    LEFT JOIN medals ON users_medals.medal_id = medals.medal_id
    WHERE users_medals.user_id = u.user_id
    AND medals.medal_type = m.medal_type
  )
```

I think it should be possible to do this as a subjoin too but the restriction of the medal type being in another table made my head ache. It would probably be easier to write if there was a view of the two tables joined together.

Answer (score 0):

You have "GROUP BY medal_type". Since your medals table only has values of 1,2 for this column, you won't get 3 & 4 in your results.

Comment: What I'm wanting is to display only one medal from each medal_type. So for example, if the user has two "post medals", the latest one earned would be the only one displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing 3 and 4 because you are grouping it by medal type.  So 3 and 4 and the same type as 1 and 2.  If you take group by off it will show every medal.

If you want this group by but only want 3 and 4.  Then then you simply need to

```
order by m.medal_type descending
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're grouping by the medal type, it'll only select one of each type. If you want a list of all the medals a user got, why are you grouping by the medal type?

Perhaps you're looking for the highest level of the medal by type? If that's the case, you might want to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

Dalen did ask the right thing - why would you like to use GROUP BY in the first place? That's not needed in this query. GROUP BY serves a different purpose; maybe you can understand it more by checking an example like [this one](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-GROUP-BY.asp).